# Add another array in an array variable using a loop in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) is what I am trying to accomplish (the accepted answer).

```
var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

The difference is the values are stored in an array. I tried this:

```
    <?foreach($nearest_hospitals as $item):?>
    var locations = [
          [<?$item->H_NAME;?>, <?$item->H_LAT;?>, <?$item->H_LONG;?>, <?$item->H_ID;?>],
    ];
    <?endforeach?>
```

With this, the map is not showing. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: I'd arrange it into the correct form of arrays and then just use json_encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure proper encoding of the resulting javascript object I would suggest creating a php array of all of your elements then calling json_encode to produce the json.

```
<?php

   $locations = array();
   foreach($nearest_hospitals as $item){
        $locations[] = array($item->H_NAME,$item->H_LAT,$item->H_LONG,$item->H_ID);
   }
?>
var locations = <?= json_encode($locations) ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, use [Array.push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

Sample code:

```
var locations = new Array;
<?foreach($nearest_hospitals as $item):?>
    locations.push(
          [<?$item->H_NAME;?>, <?$item->H_LAT;?>, <?$item->H_LONG;?>, <?$item->H_ID;?>]
    );
<?endforeach?>
```

Ps: I haven't tested this code yet.

Comment: Don't expect sample code works without any adjustments. You need to read and understand the idea and code by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your locations variable outside the loop. Example:

```
var locations = {};
<?foreach($nearest_hospitals as $item):?>
    locations.push(
          [<?$item->H_NAME;?>, <?$item->H_LAT;?>, <?$item->H_LONG;?>, <?$item->H_ID;?>],
    );
<?endforeach?>
```

Comment: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'`

Comment: Sorry, declare like var locations = Array();
And use {} in place of [] like:
locations.push(
          {<?$item->H_NAME;?>, <?$item->H_LAT;?>, <?$item->H_LONG;?>, <?$item->H_ID;?>},
    );